# Trigger event every X seconds in Cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4

I'm currently developing a system in Cakephp 3.4 which needs to check for connectivity with another machine every X seconds by sending a 'ping'.

I've read the cookbook section about Events in the docs but I couldn't find any Events that trigger themselves automatically within an interval of time in an infinite way.

Where should this loop be placed within the framework structure?.

Comment: If the process is going to run longer than a matter of seconds? If so a cron job or a system monitoring service would be a better option IMO. PHP is not designed to be a long running process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a shell.](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html) 
Either use a cron job to run it every X seconds or add the loop to the shell and start it in the background.

Comment: You can also find how to set a Shell up as a crontab here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html

Comment: It seems this is exactly what I was searching for, thanks! :)